# I have a problem with the django authenticate function

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication

When I input the same username and password as in the database it shows "invalid credentials" instead of "Success".

def login(request):
    if request.method  == 'POST':

```
    username           = request.POST.get('user')
    password1          = request.POST.get('password1')
    a                  = authenticate( username=username, password=password1)
    if a is not None:
        return HttpResponse("Success")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Invalid Credentials")
return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Comment: How did you *create* a user? Is the password hashed?

Comment: actually, I directly inserted the username and password in the database.Also, I have hashed passwords.But I'm trying to deal with the directly inserted values

Comment: well then this will not work. Django hashes the passwords when you create a user, and also *checks* if the hash matches. Storing raw passwords in the database is a *severe* security threat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the authentication itself, but with creating users. You can not create users with raw passwords in the database. Django [stores *hashed* passwords in the database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords). By default the *PBKDF2* hasher is used, although you can configure that. That means that a password looks like:

```
algorithm$iterations$salt$hash
```

The authentication module will hash the password you give, and check if this matches.

You can make use of the [**`createsuperuser`** management command [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser) to make a superuser:

```
django-admin createsuperuser
```

or you can change the password of a user with the [**`changepassword`** management command [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-changepassword):

```
django-admin changepassword username
```

For normal users, you can make for example through the admin pages, or with the the [**`.create_user(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) in the shell:

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='username', password='thepassword')
<User: username>
```